# CSS best practices while using Django

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I've been working in a project for about 6 months, and I've been adding more urls each time. Right now, I'm coming into the problem that when I'm using `extend 'base.html'` into another pages, the CSS overlap, and I'm getting a mess.

My question is: Which are the best practices when using `extend` for CSS files? Should every html file I create have it's own css? Or should I have one css that is called in the base.html file and from there all of the other html files take their styling from?

This is what my base.html looks like:

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
    <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
    <meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />

    </script>

  </head>
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    html {
      font-size: 10px;
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }

    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #ea0a8e;
      font-size: 18px;
    }

    header {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      background: #121212;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container {
      max-width: 120rem;
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .menu-toggle {
      position: fixed;
      top: 2.5rem;
      right: 2.5rem;
      color: #eeeeee;
      font-size: 3rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      z-index: 1000;
      display: none;
    }

    nav {
      padding-top: 5rem;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 1.6rem;

    }

    .logo {
      font-size: 3rem;
      font-weight: 300;
      transform: translateX(-100rem);
      animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
      color: #ea0a8e;

    }

    .logo span {
      color: white;
    }

    nav ul {
      display: flex;
      padding: 0;

    }

    nav ul li {
      list-style: none;
      transform: translateX(100rem);
      animation: slideIn .5s forwards;
    }

    nav ul li:nth-child(1) {
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    nav ul li:nth-child(2) {
      animation-delay: .5s;
    }

    nav ul li:nth-child(3) {
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }

    nav ul li:nth-child(4) {
      animation-delay: 1.5s;
    }

    nav ul li:nth-child(5) {
      animation-delay: 1s;
    }

    nav ul li:nth-child(6) {
      animation-delay: .5s;
    }

    nav ul li:nth-child(7) {
      animation-delay: 0s;
    }

    nav ul li a {
      padding: 1rem 0;
      margin: 0 3rem;
      position: relative;
    }

    nav ul li a:last-child {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    nav ul li a::before,
    nav ul li a::after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      width: 100%;
      height: 2px;
      background-color: crimson;
      left: 0;
      transform: scaleX(0);
      transition: all .5s;
    }

    nav ul li a::before {
      top: 0;
      transform-origin: left;
    }

    nav ul li a::after {
      bottom: 0;
      transform-origin: right;
    }


    nav ul li a:hover::before,
    nav ul li a:hover::after {
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }

    @keyframes slideIn {
      from {}

      to {
        transform: translateX(0);
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

      .menu-toggle {
        display: block;
      }

      nav {
        padding-top: 0;
        display: none;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        height: 100vh;
        text-align: center;
      }

      nav ul {
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      nav ul li {
        margin-top: 5rem;
      }

      nav ul li a {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
      }

      .logo {
        font-size: 5rem;
      }

      body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 11px;
      }

      body {
        scrollbar-width: thin;
        scrollbar-color: var(--thumbBG) var(--scrollbarBG);
      }

      body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        background: var(--scrollbarBG);
      }

      body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        background-color: var(--thumbBG);
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 3px solid var(--scrollbarBG);
      }

    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <nav>
        <h1 class="logo">GP Recon<span>ciliation</span></a></h1>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="{% url 'dashboard' %}">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'stats' %}">Stats</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'addtransaction' %}">Add transaction</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'upload' %}">Docs</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'suggestion' %}">Suggestions</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Log out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>

    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}



  </body>
```

This is the testing.html file I'm extending the base to:

```
{% extends 'pythonApp/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<style>
    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: #121212;
    }
    li{
        list-style: none;
        position: relative;
    }
    ul.child{
        display: none;
        width: 100%! important;

    }
    ul.parent > li{
        background: #ea0a8e;
        width: 20%;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        color: white;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <nav id="navigation">
      <ul class="parent">
        <li>Human Resources
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Contact </li>
            <li>Escalation </li>
            <li>Performance</li>
            <li>Resource </li>
            <li>Benefits</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Mision
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Mission</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Open 
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Field</li>
            <li>Office</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Training
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Training </li>
            <li>GP </li>
            <li>Mobile </li>
            <li>GP </li>
            <li>Field!</li>
            <li>Ready!</li>
            <li>Customer</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Commissions
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Mobile</li>
            <li>Quotas</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Operations
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Aud</li>
            <li>Ops</li>
            <li>To Documents</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Help
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Help</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Documents
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Documents</li>
          </ul>
        </li>    
        <li>Resources
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Resources</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Dep
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Dep</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>District
          <ul class="child">
            <li>District</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Store
          <ul class="child">
            <li>Store</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>ME
          <ul class="child">
            <li>ME</li>
          </ul>
        </li>  
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $('ul.parent > li').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('ul.child').show(200);
        }, function() {
            $(this).find('ul.child').hide(400);
        });
    });

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

What's happening is that the css effects that are in the styling of base.html are also applying to the test.html file

Comment: Look into BEM, SPA, Shadow DOM and CSS encapsulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your base.html I'd only include styles that are applied to all/several pages on your website.

And then include page-specific styles in that page HTML file.

Storing all styles in 1 file is definitely not a good practice.

Also, I see that you write your CSS selectors using tags like `li` or `nav`, this is generally a bad practice cause it leads to unexpected style overlaps. Use explicit declarative CSS classes for your elements (like in BEM methodology for example) and select elements by classes, not tags.

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking about it and I think the solution would be creating classes for each element and specify exactly which element I want to style. I'm new to html/css but this should do the job. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this sounds like a good plan

Answer (score 1):

Django provides django.contrib.staticfiles which is tasked with static files(CSS,JavaScript,media).In a nut shell each template in the app will inherit the base static folder in your app

[Read the below doc and see how to configure the static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/)

Comment: And what happens when I don't want certain element to inherit the attributes from the base.html to the new template? In my case, an animation is being inherited and it makes a mess in the design.

Comment: few things you can do
1.Treat the template as an independent
2.Make used of the {% block[s] %} structure
\

Answer (score 0):

you can add your static files in your template:

```
{% extends 'pythonApp/base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'pathtostaticfile' %}" />
...
```